# How to correctly implement a linked list class in C++

Tags: c++

I'm trying to implement a simple list in C++ but I'm stuck with writing the add function

When adding one element it works fine but then it just keeps adding the element indefinitely

This is weird because I'm making sure to only add to the tail of the linked list and the last element is always NULL.

The result is correct only if we add to a list containing just one element.

```
#include <iostream>

using namespace std;

class List {

    int value;

    public:
    List(int value);
    List* next;
    List* tail();
    void add(int value);
    void reverse();
    void echo();
};


List::List(int value){
    List::value = value;
    List::next = NULL;
}
List* List::tail(){
    List* tail = this;
    for(;tail->next!=NULL; tail = tail->next);
    return tail;
}
void List::add(int value)
{
    List next (value);
    List* tail = List::tail();
    tail->next = &next;
}
void List::echo()
{
    cout << List::value << "    ";

    if(next!=NULL){
        next->echo();
    }
}

int main(){
    List list (3);
    list.add(1);
    list.add(2);

    list.echo();
}
```

Comment: `&next` is a pointer to a local variable so causes undefined behaviour when it is dereferenced later

Comment: Have you got any textbooks?  The syntax seems weird.

Comment: @prehistoricpenguin nope, I just write beautiful code

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The variable

```
List next (value);
```

is automatic, so it exists from the line of its declaration till the end of the `add()` function. Once the function returns, the variable no longer exists and the pointer you assigned with

```
tail->next = &next;
```

becomes invalid.

You should allocate the 'next' item at a heap:

```
List* next = new List(value);
```

and append it to the list with

```
tail->next = next;
```

Comment: `new` does not necessarily allocate on the heap. The important part is that `new` creates an object with dynamic storage duration.

Comment: might be an idea to mention `delete`ing the created nodes

Comment: To avoid the memory leak.

Comment: Why should I delete the created nodes?

Comment: @AlanBirtles Yup, I might also mention appropriate design of List and ListNode to separate responsibilities, as well as lacking methods to seek and remove items, possible adding at front and at end of a list and even at arbitrary place anywhere inside a list. And not forget a missing implementation of `Reverse()` method (which requires separating List from ListNode or at least a double linking, so it can find the true start of the list). But I didn't like writing a programming manual. Not this time at least.

Comment: @CiaPan you're right, I'm actually just doing this to remember how to remember how to reverse a linked list

Comment: @Tawfik So you want to reverse a list? You need to know the first item of the list then. Having the `List` class representing a list's node is bad in this situation, as the node has no ability to find out, whether it is is the first node or it is a 'next' after some other node. As a result it can't reliably do reversing in general.

Comment: @CiaPan I just got that we can't assign to `this` . I understand why we should differentiate between `ListNode` and `List`

Answer (score 1):

The problem is this part of `add` : `List next (value);`.
Overall your `add` function is correct, but you're creating an object that once you exit the function, will be destroyed. When you're assigning `tail->next = &next;`, inside the `add` function it's fine, but once you exit the function, that piece of memory doesn't exist anymore.

You have to create a new piece of memory somehow, for example using `List* next = new List(value);`.

And now that you have manually allocated memory, you need to `delete` all of them once your object is destroyed, to release the memory, otherwise you'll get a memory leak.

Comment: why should I deallocate it? it's part of my list

Comment: Right, I should've been more precise. When you're object is destroyed you should deallocate it.

Comment: I4ve modified my answer.